# Invalid Big number

Tags: solidity, remix

When i try to deploy my example contract it gives me the error creation of Auction errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.0.8)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.5.2;


contract Auction{
    mapping(address=> uint)public bids;

    struct Car{
        string description;
        uint value;
        uint built_year;
    }
    
    Car public private_car;
    mapping(address=> Car) public cars;
    
    
    constructor(string memory _description, uint _value, uint _built_year) public{
    private_car.description = _description;
    private_car.value = _value;
    private_car.built_year = _built_year;
    
       cars[msg.sender] = private_car;
    }
    
    function bid() payable public{
        bids[msg.sender] = msg.value;
    }
    
    
}
```

Why it gives this error when i pass nothing in the constructor? It works fine if i pass something in the constructor at the time of deployment.

Comment: The problem is in the deployer, not in your smart contract code.

Comment: please post the transaction hash

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa what do you mean by that? i am deploying on Remix JavaScript VM with the same account that i'm using while passing the parameters on the constructor

Comment: @Nulik I am not getting the transaction hash. all i am getting in the logs is the error
"creation of Auction errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.0.8)"

Answer (score 6):

If you have a constructor with arguments and you don't have an empty constructor defined, you *have to* give the arguments when deploying the contract. If you try to deploy without arguments you get an error - Remix just seems to give a bit strange error.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of deployment of your contract in Remix, you get a drop-down option where you need to pass all the values defined in the constructor. This will be a predefined value for your contract.

```
 constructor(string memory _description, uint _value, uint _built_year) public{
    private_car.description = _description;
    private_car.value = _value;
    private_car.built_year = _built_year;
    
       cars[msg.sender] = private_car;
    }
```

In your case, you need to provide these values:

> **_description**,  **_value**,  **_built_year**

Answer (score 0):

You're probably leaving out some required part of the input, i.e. the function expects 3 fiels of data, and you're providing only 2.